# Confused with foreach and multidimensional array - PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Ok, so arrays are my weakness and I'm struggling with this. It's probably dead simple too. Basically, I have an array which is

Code:

```
    Array
    (
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => getalbum
                [fql_result_set] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [aid] => 187046464639937_101906
                                [name] => photo tab
                                [cover_pid] => 187046464639937_1661168
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [aid] => 187046464639937_99627
                                [name] => Cover Photos
                                [cover_pid] => 187046464639937_1661054
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => getcover
                [fql_result_set] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [src] => http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/526499_403098366368078_187046464639937_1661168_217706037_s.jpg
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [src] => http://photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/562470_403049039706344_187046464639937_1661054_361917190_s.jpg
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

    )
```

I'm using a foreach to call the array by using
PHP Code:

```
foreach($fql_query_obj['data'] as $albums){
    foreach($albums['fql_result_set'] as $album){
        //print_r($album);
        if (   ($album['name'] != "Wall Photos")
            && ($album['name'] != "Cover Photos") 
            && ($album['name'] != "photo tab"))
        {
             echo $album['name'].' :: '.$album['aid'];
             echo '<img src="'.$album['src'].'" /><br />';
        }    
     }
}
```

Now it seems to go through the getalbum array then the getcover. How can I do it so it merges both of them together?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the output you're expecting? Your question is unclear at the end. What do you mean by "merges both of them together"?

Answer (score 0):

How do you get your data, some kind of database? Maybe you can merge it when you fetching that data?

Anyway, if your data is always ordered that way (matching arrays, one with first part of data, second with additional) how about something like that?

```
foreach($fql_query_obj['data'][0]['fql_result_set'] as $key_album => $album){
    //print_r($album);
    if (   ($album['name'] != "Wall Photos")
        && ($album['name'] != "Cover Photos") 
        && ($album['name'] != "photo tab"))
    {
         echo $album['name'].' :: '.$album['aid'];
         echo '<img src="'.$fql_query_obj['data'][1]['fql_result_set'][$key_album]['src'].'" /><br />';
    }    
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost the same way I ended up figuring out after I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to iterate the queries (`getalbum` and `getcover`).  Instead, you probably want to iterate the albums and treat the cover and album data as a unified thing.  I would try restructuring the data to be easier to work with:

```
list($albumsQuery, $coversQuery) = $fql_query_obj['data'];
$albums = array();

foreach ($albumsQuery['fql_result_set'] as $album) {
    $albums[] = $album;
}

for ($i = 0, $numAlbums = count($albums); $i < $numAlbums; ++$i) {
    $albums[$i] = array_merge($albums[$i], $coversQuery['fql_result_set'][$i]);
}

foreach ($albums as $album) {
    // Here, $album contains data from both arrays
}
```

Note that this assumes there are no conflicting keys (there aren't in your example data), and there are lots of other ways to do this.